# pass my table name as parameter in sql query

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql

I need help with a query. In my query I want to pass my table name as parameter. This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONVERT (varchar, InspectDateTime) AS 'Inspect Date Time', 
    CONVERT (varchar, SynDateTime) AS 'Sync Date Time', 
    Employee, 
    ROUND(OverAllPercentage, 2) AS Grade 
FROM 
    Table_Name 
WHERE 
    (DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, InspectDateTime), 0) 
    BETWEEN 
        DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @From ), 0) AND 
        DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @To ), 0)) 
ORDER BY 
    'Inspect Date Time'
```

Here I want to pass the `Table_Name` as parameter. Please note that this query is already taking two arguments as parameter, namely `"@From`" and "`@To`"

Comment: which database are you using? (generation of dynamic sql differs from db to db)

Comment: Be aware that your order-by clause will sort dates alphabetically. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with MS SQL you can do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetMyStuff
(
    @From datetime,
    @To datetime,
    @TableName nvarchar(100)
)
AS

exec('    
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CONVERT (varchar, InspectDateTime) AS ''Inspect Date Time'', 
        CONVERT (varchar, SynDateTime) AS ''Sync Date Time'', 
        Employee, 
        ROUND(OverAllPercentage, 2) AS Grade 
    FROM 
        ' + @TableName + ' 
    WHERE 
        (DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, InspectDateTime), 0) 
        BETWEEN 
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ' + @From + '), 0) AND 
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ' + @To + '), 0)) 
    ORDER BY 
        1
');
```

and then just call it

```
sp_GetMyStuff '2011-05-05', '2011-06-05', 'TBL_MYTABLE'
```

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head.  Can you use the + concat character with a datetime and a varchar?  I would have guessed no, but am not certain from memory.

Comment: Hi Balexandre, thanks for your post. It worked fine after casting @From and @To into varchar.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, if you want to "parametrize" the table name, you have to use dynamic SQL

If so, you **must read** Erland's [The Curse and Blessing of dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) as an intro.

So basically, you need to build up your SQL statement as a string, and then execute it. There is no other way to "parametrize" the table name in a SQL Server T-SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks marc for your comment :)

Answer (score 3):

OK, assuming you're using SQL Server (judging by the `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` functions), you'll need to

1. construct a concatenated sql command
   as string (taking care not to allow
   SQL injection: i.e. you should check
   that your `table_name` variable is a
   valid table name by looking up
   possible names form
   `information_schema` and validating
   etc.)
2. execute your dynamic sql using
   `sp_executesql`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: +1 vote to this answer for linking to sp_executesql. Since the poster not only wants to query a dynamic table, but pass date parameters as well sp_executesql is the only way to go.  The link explains how to pass the @From and @To into the dynamic statement.

Comment: Thanks davek for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks balexandre. The final query after minor modification(casting @From,@To into varchar) is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetMyStuff

@TableName VARCHAR(128),
@From DATETIME,
@To DATETIME

AS

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT (varchar, InspectDateTime) AS ''Inspect Date Time'', CONVERT (varchar, SynDateTime) AS ''Sync Date Time'', Employee, ROUND(OverAllPercentage, 2) AS Grade
FROM ' + @TableName + '
WHERE
(DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, InspectDateTime), 0) BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,'''+ CAST(@From AS VARCHAR(100)) +''' ), 0)
AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,'''+ CAST(@To AS VARCHAR(100)) +'''), 0))
ORDER BY ''Inspect Date Time'''
EXEC (@sql)

GO
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!