# Pass in SQL query the table name as parameter

Tags: string, pandas, postgresql

A possible solution for this question is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6223961/12343395
It will probably work with a lot of work around.
But I have stored my table names in string format and want to call them as needed.
I am using Pandas [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html). So as in `params`, I am passing, the table name and a few parameters in the `WHERE` section.
The `WHERE` section is fine, since the parameters are originally strings. But in the `FROM` section,
I really want the `schema.table` as a non-string.
Here is a snippet.

```
SELECT "rainfall(mm)","tmin(C)","tmax(C)","TimeStamp"
FROM crop_tables[choose_crop][0]
WHERE "District_Name" = %s AND "Season" = %s
ORDER BY "TimeStamp" ASC
```

where `crop_tables[choose_crop][0]` is `'sagita_historic.soyabean_daily_analyses'` in this case.
But `FROM` will throw an error since it doesn't accept strings. So in essence, I wish to strip the `'sagita_historic.soyabean_daily_analyses'` as a non-string.
Is it possible to do so?
Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest using `f-string` here if you are using python version `>= 3.5`

Comment: I would strongly recommend storing the crop type as a column in one table rather than having many different tables with the same columns. This will make it easier to query.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand but maybe this will do?

```
SELECT "rainfall(mm)","tmin(C)","tmax(C)","TimeStamp"
FROM f"{crop_tables[choose_crop][0]}"
WHERE "District_Name" = %s AND "Season" = %s
ORDER BY "TimeStamp" ASC
```

Comment: Hi. Postgresql doesn't accept "f" as a valid formatter. Though I tried your suggestion by passing it in 'params'. It still accepts it as a string. I want it to be non-string.